# Arduino ESP edit big JSON file - wear leveling

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, esp32, arduino-esp8266

I have a "big" JSON file about 1000 objects.
Using https://arduinojson.org/ to serialize / deserialize.

```
void ConfigFile_Save_Variable(String VarName, String VarValue) {
  Serial.print("ConfigFile_Save_Variable: ");
  Serial.print(VarName); Serial.print("="); Serial.print(VarValue);

  File configFile = SPIFFS.open("/config.json", "r");
  if (!configFile) {
    Serial.println("- failed to open config file for writing");
    return;
  }

  DynamicJsonDocument doc(2048);
  deserializeJson(doc, configFile);
  serializeJson(doc, Serial);
  configFile.close();
  //
  doc[VarName] = VarValue;
  //
  configFile = SPIFFS.open("/config.json", "w");
  serializeJson(doc, configFile);
  serializeJson(doc, Serial);
  configFile.close();
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println(" - config.json saved - OK.");
```

If I want to edit only 1 object and save the JSON file, the whole file is written again.
This is bad for wear leveling, as it write all data again tho only 1 object has been changed.

So I'm looking for a way to only write the change not the whole file. Tried looking everywhere without luck.

Comment: Perhaps an arduino is not powerful enough for your goals. Did you consider some [RaspBerryPi](http://raspberrypi.org/)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It seems not to be power that is the problem, but just how the file API handles saving changes. But the question basically boils down to 'is there a library that can only save the changed parts of files', and questions for libraries etc are off-topic. Certainly, without context on what kind of changes are made and expected to be handled that way, since e.g. insertion/deletion by definition would require a rewrite of everything after the modification point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to break up the JSON - write each top level object to its own file. You already have the labels for the objects, use those as filenames prefixed with `/config/` or `/c/` if you need more space for the label name.

Let's look at why what you're asking for from SPIFFs doesn't work.

JSON is serialized for storage as text. For example, the object

```
{
  label_0: {
    label_a: "small string",
    label_b: 1
    },
  label_1: {
    label_c: "another string",
    label_d: "more string"
  }
}
```

is serialized as

```
{"label_0":{"label_a":"small string","label_b":1},"label_1":{"label_c":"another string","label_d":"more string"}}
```

SPIFFS splits stored files into pages of fixed size. It has to write an entire page to flash each time - it can't just write the changed bytes; that's not how flash storage works.

Suppose `label_a` becomes shorter - just `"s"`. Then everything after `label_a` would have to be shifted down in the file. For SPIFFS to do what you're asking, it would have to write a page and remember that only part of the page was in use.

If the value of `label_a` becomes larger - `"this is a much longer string"` then everything would have to be shifted up in the file. SPIFFS would have to allocate a new page to store the overflow and remember that only part of it was in use.

Keep in mind that the only way SPIFFS can remember which blocks are in use is by writing that information to flash as well.

That's a lot to ask of a simple filesystem.

Let's also get some perspective on the situation. How big is the file, and how often is it written? If you have 1000 objects and each object takes, say, 200 bytes to store, your JSON would be about 20,000 bytes. An average ESP8266 or ESP32 has 4MB of flash, with maybe 1.5MB available for SPIFFS. You can store 20,000 bytes 75 times in 1.5MB - so you probably have a factor of around 75x or a bit less for wear leveling.

The flash in most ESP8266's and ESP32's is rated for 100,000 writes (in practice it would usually last much longer). So with wear leveling you could probably write a 20,000 byte file 750,000 times without expecting to see errors.

Are you actually likely to write this file even 1000 or 10,000 times?

If you are - this seems like an odd scenario for a configuration file, and you should rethink how you're handling this file and what it's doing.

If not then this isn't actually a problem.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Manual wear leveling is very hard, and leveling may be automatic anyway. I would separate out the often changed config options into a different file so you write less each time, and only write to disk when you absolutely have to (ie: program end)

If the length of the json file changes, ie: you change "true" to "false" the entire file must be rewritten because the [disc] space that must be allocated to the file has now changed.
If you reserve a set number of characters for each config value, or use only x digit numbers as config values, you may be able to directly rewrite the binary data on the disk without interfacing with the file at all. But that would require some extremely low level programming, and knowledge of exact memory addresses.
In addition, because you are using flash memory for the storage, you would still have to read, update, and write a full memory block for every change made. Over time, especially if you only update one value with any regularity, this may be more damaging to the disk in the long run compared to a full rewrite.

Desktop SSDs will automatically level wear across the entire disk. If the esp does the same, then you shouldn't have to worry about leveling wear yourself, but rather keeping the file size to a minimum for when you do rewrite it.

Given the above, one possible solution would be to separate out the often rewritten config options into a separate file, and keep the rarely rewritten ones in your main file. You could also keep all config data in memory, and only rewrite the file on program end, though this only applies if you don't constantly start/stop your program.
Taking separation to the extreme you could theoretically use a separate file for every config option, which would allow you to only rewrite one value at a time.